# Can badge points requirements be adjusted?

Tags: discussion, badges

Can the mods adjust the requirements of badges whose points requirements make them impossible to earn given the userbase of this forum?

Comment: Isn't this the same question as this one? http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/254/can-we-refocus-certain-badges

Comment: Well in that question I was thinking more in terms of the general focus of the badge.  In this one I'm talking about point requirements.

Comment: I think the answer is the same. The badges are general for all SO websites.